# Transferring MongoDB data

Tags: mongodb

So, as the documentation says, by default, it stores data in the data/db/ directory. As I can see through the file manager, the folder is empty. I guess the documents are hidden there.

So, If I pull a repository with this folder from another PC, will I be able to access this data through MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the documents are hidden there

Unlikely. I'm betting that your data dir is set to another value.

> If I pull a repository with this folder from another PC

This *may* work, but, at best, it'll overwrite your local data files. At worst, it'll overwrite your local data files and mongodb won't boot with your new data files.

A recommended/supported way is to use `mongodump`/`mongorestore`. Bonus point: you won't have to care about where your data files are on both computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed MongoDB for example from Debian/Ubuntu package the data directory will be `/var/lib/mongodb`.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/982673/where-is-mongo-database-folder-on-the-filesystem